# Bone heat weighting error after all solutions

Tags: rigging

I have checked almost all the questions about that here but I could not find any right solution for my case. I did remove doubles and applied all modifiers dissolved vertices. I will attach the blender file so you can open it and try by your self.
Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yk6rvcwtdd37ibx/Char01.blend?dl=0